# How to retrieve nested list for document

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, wtforms

I am using MongoDB and Flask. In my model, I have the following:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    types = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, default="Feature")
    geometry = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Geometry'))
    properties = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Properties'))

class Geometry(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    types = db.StringField(default="Point",required=True)
    coordinates = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Coordinates'))

class Coordinates(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    longitude = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    latitude = db.StringField(max_length=255)

class Properties(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    types = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    location_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    feed_url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    content_url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    date_added = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    date_crawled = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
```

As of now, I'm using:

```
Post.objects.get_or_404(title=title)
```

to retrieve everything from the class post.

My question is: does anyone know how to retrieve the listfield properties and also get the value of url?

I need this because I am trying to repopulate a form so that when the user presses "edit" it will show the details of what the user has previously added in the form.

When I try:

```
Properties.objects.get_or_404(url=url)
```

it gives me `AttributeError: type object 'Properties' has no attribute 'objects'`.

Answer (score 0):

You used `EmbeddedDocument` so it's just path of `Post` model and `EmbeddedDocument` doesn't have `object` propery because it just path of `Document` as `DictField`.

To find `Post` where `properties.url == url` use next code:

```
Post.objects.get_or_404(title=title, properties__url=url)
```

But you will get `Post` entity and must find specific property manualy. For example:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    def get_property_by_url(self, url):
        for property in self.properties:
            if property.url == url:
                return property
        abort(404)
```